# Cannot locate psagent job type in Workload Scheduler 9.4

Tags: peoplesoft, workload-scheduler

I am trying to create specific jobs for PeopleSoft. I am in the
Workload designer and I can see where to create new jobs for SAP,
Oracle E-Business, etc but I can not find the job type for PeopleSoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as any new jobs created via the Workload Designer you will
select Job Type > ERP > Access Method

As far as existing jobs... composer and the database look is the same as
it was in 8.6

This is the definition in 9.4 for example

PEOLESOFT#TEST_XRFWIN_PSOFT
 SCRIPTNAME "-process XRFWIN -type 'SQR Report' -runcontrol 1"
 STREAMLOGON twsuser
 DESCRIPTION "Test job"
 TASKTYPE OTHER
 RECOVERY STOP

For more details...
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/distr/src_tsweb/General_Help/Creating_exec_jobs_t.htm